# Number theory problem: When is this sequence bounded? (Putnam 1991, ACPS)

Tags: number-theory

This is a problem in one of the exercises of *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving* by Paul Zeitz, originally set in the 1991 Putnam exam.

Define $S(n):= n - m^2, n \in \mathbb{N_0}$
with $m^2$ being the largest perfect square $\leq n$.

Let us define $(a_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ with $a_0 = A$ and other values defined by the recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = a_n + S(a_n)$.

For which values of A does this sequence converge to a finite limit?

I have a proof that says it only converges for perfect squares, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I'll post it here in a while.

Comment: I believe you're correct that it converges only for perfect squares.

Comment: @GregMartin any evidence for this?

Comment: Well, I have a proof. It's not clear to me whether you wanted proofs posted, since you said you had one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{a_n\}$ is a nondecreasing sequence of integers, it converges if and only if it stabilizes after finitely many terms. In particular, it converges if and only if $a_{n+1}=a_n$ for some $n$, or equivalently $S(a_n)=0$ for some $n$, or equivalently if $a_n$ is a perfect square for some $n$.

We claim that the only way that $\{a_n\}$ can contain a perfect square is if $A$ itself is a perfect square. Proof by contradiction: suppose $A$ is not a square but $\{a_n\}$ contains a perfect square; let $k$ be the smallest index such that $a_k$ is a perfect square (note $k\ge1$), and choose $m$ so that $a_k=m^2$. What could $a_{k-1}$ have been? Certainly $a_{k-1}<m^2$.

It's impossible that $a_{k-1}\le(m-1)^2$, because $S(j)\le2m-4$ for all $j\le(m-1)^2$, and hence $a_{k-1}+S(a_{k-1}) \le (m-1)^2+2m-4 < m^2$.

But it's also impossible that $(m-1)^2<a_{k-1}<m^2$, because then $a_{k-1}+S(a_{k-1}) = a_{k-1}+(a_{k-1}-(m-1)^2)$ has the same parity as $(m-1)^2$, hence cannot equal $m^2$.

Comment: Almost exactly the same as mine (except for the fact that yours looks like a *real* proof)!